# RestSharp for PCL not returning data from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I use this [sample tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to create a simple Web API.

Then I downloaded the PCL version of RestSharp from [here](https://github.com/Geodan/geoserver-csharp/tree/master/RestSharp), compiled and tried to execute this test code:

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:18506/api/");
            var request = new RestRequest("products", Method.GET);
            client.ExecuteAsync<List<Product>>(request, response =>
            {
                foreach (var a in response.Data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
                }
            });
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Nothing is being written to the console and if I put a break point within the call back, it is not hit.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've triggered an asynchronous HTTP call and never seem to be waiting for it to complete. Try waiting or your unit test might finish much before the Web API is even hit by the request:

```
client.ExecuteAsync<List<Product>>(request, response =>
{
    ...
}).Result;
```

But in a unit test you probably don't need to be complicated your life with asynchronous HTTP calls. Just use a standard synchronous call and assert on the results received.

Comment: I atleast expected to see something written to the console or have the breakpoint hit within the return lamda.  This is the PCL version of RestSharp, which does not have a synchronous API.  Also, the response of client.ExectuteAsync is RestRequestAsyncHandle which does not have a Result property.  I am mostly using this as a learning test to figure out how RestSharp works.

Comment: You cannot expect something like that with an asynchronous call which returns immediately and your test terminates bringing the AppDomain down. So there might not be time for the request to even be sent before your tests terminates the application.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are saying.  Let me try waiting on result to complete and post back.

Comment: Thanks, that was mostly it. Modified test to wait to result returned.